# C# Convert Char to Byte (Hex representation)

Tags: c#, byte, type-conversion, hex

This seems to be an easy problem but i can't figure out.

I need to convert this character **<** in byte(hex representation), but if i use

```
byte b = Convert.ToByte('<');
```

i get **60** (decimal representation) instead of **3c**.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`60 == 0x3C`.

You already have your correct answer but you're looking at it in the wrong way.

`0x` is the hexadecimal prefix
 `3C` is 3 x 16 + 12

Answer (score 18):

You could use the [`BitConverter.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tostring.aspx) method to convert a byte array to hexadecimal string:

```
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(new byte[] { Convert.ToByte('<') });
```

or simply:

```
string hex = Convert.ToByte('<').ToString("x2");
```

Comment: Thank you but i need a byte, if after conversion i use byte[] b = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hex); i get a byte array with 51 and 67 values. I need 3c.

Comment: If you need a byte then don't call `.ToString`, simply: `byte b = Convert.ToByte('<');`. Also the `GetBytes` method doesn't do what you think it does. It doesn't expect a hex string. It expects a simple string where each character is converted to a byte using the specified encoding - it has nothing to do with hex. You should do the following if you want to get the original byte array from a hex string: http://stackoverflow.com/a/311179/29407

Answer (score 6):

```
char ch2 = 'Z';
Console.Write("{0:X} ", Convert.ToUInt32(ch2));
```

Answer (score 4):

> get 60 (decimal representation) instead of 3c.

No, you don't get any representation. You get a `byte` containing the value 60/3c in some *internal* representation. When you *look at it*, i.e., when you convert it to a string (explicitly with `ToString()` or implicitly), you get the **decimal representation 60**.

Thus, you have to make sure that you *explicitly* convert the byte to string, **specifying the base you want**. `ToString("x")`, for example will convert a number into a **hexadecimal** representation:

```
byte b = Convert.ToByte('<');  
String hex = b.ToString("x");
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to convert the numeric value to hex using `ToString("x")`:

```
string asHex = b.ToString("x");
```

However, be aware that you code to convert the "<" character to a byte will work for that particular character, but it won't work for non-ANSI characters (that won't fit in a byte).